# Print Even and Odd numbers in c# using two thread ie even thread and odd thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

/*My requirements is 
one threads should print even numbers and the other should print odd numbers.
These threads should print the numbers in order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...)

I have done this code but when my commenting either method countThreadOdd.Start() or countThreadEven.Start(), it is not printing only even or odd numbers.*/

```
class Program
{
    static Object locker = new Object();
    static LinkedList<int> number = new LinkedList<int>();
    static int counter = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread countThreadOdd = new Thread(oddThread);
        Thread countThreadEven = new Thread(evenThread);

        //Thread Start
        countThreadOdd.Start();
        countThreadEven.Start();

        //main thread will untill below thread is in exection mode
        countThreadOdd.Join(10);
        countThreadEven.Join(10);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //Odd Thread
    public static void oddThread()
    {
        for (; counter < 10; )
        {
            //Lock the another thread to enter in critial area
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (counter % 2 != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(counter);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Even Thread
    public static void evenThread()
    {
        for (; counter < 10; )
        {
            //Lock the another thread to enter in critial area
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (counter % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(counter);  
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you only run one of the threads, what increments `counter`if it's not odd/even?

Comment: Yes counter not incrementing, so I am not getting desire output when I am running only one of thread. Do you have any better solution for this

Comment: In other words, this is to be expected by your design. Is it a requirement that the program still work if only one thread is allowed to run? That is, should it still count just odd or even numbers?

Comment: As an aside, why does this use threads at all?

Comment: Yes my requirement is like that only when I run even thread it should print even number and when I run odd thread it should print odd number.
and I run both thread is should print alternate i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: I assumed that this was an academic assignment. Is a problem you came up with on your own?

Comment: No, it is not academic assignment. When I went through thread I found this question. Currently I am working as a software developer so no chance of academic assignment.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to alternate between two threads, you can use two `AutoResetEvent` objects to do so, like so:

```
public static void oddThread()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i +=2)
    {
        evenReady.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        oddReady.Set();
    }
}

public static void evenThread()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
    {
        oddReady.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        evenReady.Set();
    }
}
```

If you only want to run one of the threads, you can use a `ManualResetEvent` instead to effectively remove all locking.

A full example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Dmr.Common.Resources;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static EventWaitHandle evenReady;
        static EventWaitHandle oddReady;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool countOdd  = true; // Change these to true/false as wanted.
            bool countEven = true;

            if (countOdd && countEven)
            {
                evenReady = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                oddReady  = new AutoResetEvent(true); // Must be true for the starting thread.
            }
            else
            {
                evenReady = new ManualResetEvent(true);
                oddReady  = new ManualResetEvent(true);
            }

            Thread countThreadOdd = new Thread(oddThread);
            Thread countThreadEven = new Thread(evenThread);

            //Thread Start
            if (countOdd)
                countThreadOdd.Start();

            if (countEven)
                countThreadEven.Start();

            //main thread will untill below thread is in exection mode

            if (countOdd)
                countThreadOdd.Join();

            if (countEven)
                countThreadEven.Join();

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void oddThread()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i +=2)
            {
                evenReady.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                oddReady.Set();
            }
        }

        public static void evenThread()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
            {
                oddReady.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                evenReady.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use Interlocked to communicate between threads. Interlocked allows you to share a variable concurrently across two threads.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace InterlockedTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static long _counter = 0;

        private static void printEvenTask()
        {
            while (Interlocked.Read(ref _counter) < 100)
            {
                if (Interlocked.Read(ref _counter) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Interlocked.Read(ref _counter));
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void printOddTask()
        {
            while (Interlocked.Read(ref _counter) < 100)
            {
                if (Interlocked.Read(ref _counter) % 2 == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Interlocked.Read(ref _counter));
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task oddTask = Task.Run(() => printOddTask());
            Task evenTask = Task.Run(() => printEvenTask());

            oddTask.Wait();
            evenTask.Wait();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: those who have disliked a particular solution, pls comment as well, it helps noob readers to understand what exactly is wrong with a solution, which otherwise they may miss :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    static AutoResetEvent evenReady = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    static AutoResetEvent oddReady = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main()
    {
        Thread countThreadOdd = new Thread(oddThread);
        Thread countThreadEven = new Thread(evenThread);
        countThreadOdd.Start();
        countThreadEven.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public static void oddThread()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2)
        {              
            oddReady.Set();
            evenReady.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Odd Thread: " + i);             
            //oddReady.Set();
        }
    }

    public static void evenThread()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
        {
            oddReady.WaitOne();
            evenReady.Set();
            Console.WriteLine("Even Thread: " + i);               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using shared resource (integer variable in this case) and Task.Delay(1) which will allow loop to be paused for some time.

**Complete Program:**

```
internal class Program
{
    int counter = 1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var P = new Program();
        var t1 = P.OddThread();
        var t2 = P.EvenThread();
        //Wait for all task to complete
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public async Task OddThread()
    {
        while (counter < 10)
        {
            // This delay will allow thread to switch and loop will be paused for some time.
            await Task.Delay(1);
            //counter is shared between threads, increment the value if it is odd number
            if (counter % 2 != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    //Even Thread
    public async Task EvenThread()
    {
        while (counter < 10)
        {
            // This delay will allow thread to switch and loop will be paused for some time.
            await Task.Delay(1);
            //counter is shared between threads, increment the value if it is even number
            if (counter % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to achieve Thread synchronization between two threads for that purpose we have multiple mechanisms in c# like ManualResetEvent, AutoResetEvent, Task Parallel Library etc.

For the [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RFoWH6), I am using **AutoResetEvent**.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static AutoResetEvent are1 = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        public static AutoResetEvent are2 = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        public static int index=1;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Thread to print odd numbers
            Thread tOdd = new Thread(PrintOdd);
            //Thread to print even numbers
            Thread tEven = new Thread(PrintEven);
            tOdd.Start();
            tEven.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void PrintOdd()
        {
           while(index<=100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: {index++}");
                //sending a signal to print even number
                are2.Set();
                //block to print odd numbers and wait for getting a signal to print odd even number
                are1.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        static void PrintEven()
        {
            while (index <= 100)
            {
                //wait for getting a signal to print an even number
                are2.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: {index++}");
                //sending a signal to print an even number
                are1.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. It uses Task Library.

```
public class OddEvenThread
{
    public static async Task printEvenNumber(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
             Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        await Task.Delay(0);
    }

    private static async Task printOddNumbers(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 1)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        await Task.Delay(0);
    }

    public async static Task printNumbers(int n)
    {

        Task evenNumbers = printEvenNumber(n);
        Task oddNumbers = printOddNumbers(n);

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>() { evenNumbers, oddNumbers };

       await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you really think that this code is guaranteed to have synchronization? i believe it may go out of order as there is no guarantee other than a equal delay time for the task, which i highly suspect to work in same way 100% of the time..what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Using AutoResetEvent, threads can be made wait for each other. Here, two threads write numbers from 1 to 20:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace oddeven
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            C c = new C();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(c.PrintOdd);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(c.PrintEven);

            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
        }
    }

    class C
    { 
        AutoResetEvent e1 = new AutoResetEvent(true);
        AutoResetEvent e2 = new AutoResetEvent(true);
        int j = 1;
        public void PrintOdd()
        {
            while (j < 20)
            {
                if (j % 2 != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(j);
                    j++;
                }
                e1.Set();
                e2.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        public void PrintEven()
        {
            while (j <= 20)
            {
                e1.WaitOne();
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(j);
                    j++;
                }
                e2.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```